# UITextView doesn't play click sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In my app, I have created a UITextView and add to main view, but when it becomes first responder and start input, I can't hear keyboard click sound. Even I have enabled it in setting->sound, but still not work. Does anyone have idea on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you not enough pushing on keyboard? :)

SRSLY: sound not depends on UITextView, it depends on whether or not sound enabled and sound volume. AFAIK you can't control keyboard's click sound programmatically.

So you need to check your device sound settings.

Comment: I find when I test on iphone, the sound won't use speaker as default sound output destination.